# Возможно ли подтягивать автоматически отзывы с карточки Яндекс Карт на сайт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-embed

Подскажите, есть ли возможность подтягивать автоматически отзывы с карточки Яндекс Карт на сайт?

Если есть, какие условия использования и где с этим можно ознакомиться?

Answer (score 3):

Есть возможность вставить отзывы через [виджет](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/vidzhet-otzyvov-dobavte-otzyvy-s-yandeks-kart-na-svoy-sayt?from=SO).

Для этого надо открыть организацию на Картах, а потом скопировать код через окно "Поделиться"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там будет вот такой код

```html
<div style="width:560px;height:800px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/226327670406?comments"></iframe>
<a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/org/usadba_izmaylovo/226327670406/" target="_blank" style="box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:none;color:#b3b3b3;font-size:10px;font-family:YS Text,sans-serif;padding:0 20px;position:absolute;bottom:8px;width:100%;text-align:center;left:0">Усадьба Измайлово на карте Москвы — Яндекс.Карты</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой функциональности в JS API Яндекс карт нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать сторонние решения, например, [виджет Reviewlab](https://reviewlab.ru).
В личном кабинете создаете сущность Виджет,  добавляете ссылку на Янекс.Карты, Яндекс.Маркет. Сервис собирает оттуда отзывы, генерирует код для вставки на сайт. Вновь появляющиеся отзывы на сервисах-источниках отобразятся у Вас на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через сервис SmartWidgets с помощью [виджета Отзывы Яндекс.Карты](https://smartwidgets.ru/yandex-maps-reviews-widget/).
Указываете в сервисе URL на источник отзывов в Яндекс Картах и сервис сам подтягивает последние 50 отзывов. Есть API и множество настроек.